# Convert ADSL modem into access point for hostel lan port

Tags: router, lan, wireless-access-point, modem

I live in a hostel where a lan port is given in every room. I have a DLink 2730u ADSL modem that I'm trying to convert into an access point. I've seen many posts on the internet on how to do so. However my college network is probably different is it is not working for me. The dhcp server for the lan port changes everytime so I can't change the modem's ip address just once. Using cmd->ipconfig it lists an ip address with "preferred" in parantheses which remains the same but the dhcp server changes every time. Need help. Thanks.
Also what should i use as the modem's ip address. Some say dhcp server address, others say default gateway or router ip address(which doesn't make sense as I only have a lan port) on the internet.

Need a step by step guide. There are many options like subnet mask, domain name and multiAP isolation that I don't know what to change to.

Comment: Hold on, why do you need the DHCP server's IP address in the first place? Are you trying to set the router to have the same address as the hostel's DHCP server itself? (That's a bad idea.)

Comment: @ user1686 1 Some posts on the internet say to use my dhcp ip address as the modem's ip address.

Comment: Yeah, they mean **your** DHCP IP address (i.e. the one that your computer received via DHCP), not the DHCP server's *own* address.

Comment: @ user1686 1 I don't understand. How do I know that ip address

Comment: That's the one shown as "IPv4 address (Preferred)" in ipconfig.

Comment: @user1686 the ip address (preferred) also changes everytime I connect to the LAN port

Answer (score 0):

Whether the DHCP server's IP address keeps changing does not matter, as you should never need to use it anywhere, and you especially should not try to configure that server's IP address as the router's address. Doing so wouldn't help you and would only cause a whole lot of problems for the rest of the hostel's internet users.

If you're trying to make the router mimic your computer, then the actual address you're supposed to use is the one that was **assigned to your computer** via DHCP – i.e. the one labelled `IPv4 Address . . (Preferred)` in ipconfig.